# How to write a regular expression to match some below string using python?

Tags: python, regex

I have below text string and I want to write a regular expression to match a string pattern as below:

```
[ 1.1 ] 1. A method of providing a master
[ 12.1 ] 12. An apparatus for providing
[ 39.3 ] b. one or more control point applications
[ 39.8 ] iv. a server application programming interface
[ 30.2 ] a. a client application programming
```

I want to substitute the `] 1.` by `]` and similarly for `] 12.`,`] b.`,`] iv.`, `] a.`

Please include a case when below thing occur in regular expresison i.e. if no above pattern occurs

```
[ 1.2 ] an RFID device provided
```

I tried below regular expression but it not worked.

```
>>> st = "[ 12.1 ] 12. An apparatus for providing a master content directory within a network of devices comprising:"
>>> import re
>>> st = re.sub(r"(?:\]\s*\d+\.\s*)?","]",st)
>>> st
'][] ]1]2].]1] ]]A]n] ]a]p]p]a]r]a]t]u]s] ]f]o]r] ]p]r]o]v]i]d]i]n]g] ]a] ]m]a]s]t]e]r] ]c]o]n]t]e]n]t] ]d]i]r]e]c]t]o]r]y] ]w]i]t]h]i]n] ]a] ]n]e]t]w]o]r]k] ]o]f] ]d]e]v]i]c]e]s] ]c]o]m]p]r]i]s]i]n]g]:]'
```

Comment: Maybe `re.sub(r"\]\s*\w+\.\s*","] ",st)` will do. See https://regex101.com/r/Lp9vBQ/1. The point is that your regex matches before each char in a string because it is optional, `(?:...)?` makes it match 1 or 0 times.

Comment: you can use `re.sub(r"\]\s\w+\.","]",st)`, if you are sure that the second numbering always ends with a `.`

Comment: why did you write that `?` in the end in the regex string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that your regex matches before each char in a string because it is optional, `(?:...)?`, a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) modified with a [`?` quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), makes it match 1 or 0 times.

Also, `\d` only matches a digit, and you need to consider letters, too.

To quickly fix the issue you may use

```
st = re.sub(r"\]\s*\w+\.\s*", "] ", st)
```

See [this regex demo](http://htttp://regex101.com/r/Lp9vBQ/1). The `\w+` construct matches 1+ word chars (letters, digits or underscores).

You may make it a bit more precise if you match just 1+ digits or 1+ letters after `]` before `.`:

```
st = re.sub(r"\]\s*(?:\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)\.\s*", "] ", st)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wUZS8b/1).

Comment: what if i don't use r inside re.sub()?

Comment: @RinkuYadav It won't change anything in this case, but you should use raw strings in general when defining regex patterns to avoid issues, e.g. with `\b` as word boundaries or `\1` as backreferences.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = """
[ 1.1 ] 1. A method of providing a master
[ 12.1 ] 12. An apparatus for providing
[ 39.3 ] b. one or more control point applications
[ 39.8 ] iv. a server application programming interface
[ 30.2 ] a. a client application programming
"""
print(re.sub(r'\]\s\w{1,2}\.', '] ', s))
```

Output

```
[ 1.1 ]  A method of providing a master
[ 12.1 ]  An apparatus for providing
[ 39.3 ]  one or more control point applications
[ 39.8 ]  a server application programming interface
[ 30.2 ]  a client application programming
```